# null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null & destinationDir=null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Help me out from the hell of `null value=entry` when I try to run my `project` it gives me `error` `null value in entry: incrementalFolder=null`

- It happens when my `system unfortunately shutdown`
- Here is the `output`.

---

[image]

Comment: I am having same problem. My system shut down as well, when I was trying to generate a signed APK. Now, I get this error. How did you fix it?

Comment: If you were trying to generate a signed APK, rebuild the project first. Then, create a signing configuration. Apply the signing configuration and you should get a signed APK. check this page for how to create a gradle signing configuration. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-auto  Scroll down the the sub-title: Configure the build process to automatically sign your APK